# Python nested dictionaries - Append data to nested dict without overwriting previous data

Tags: python, dictionary

```
async for document in client.auto_role.find({}):
    if client.auto_role_cache.get(document.get("guildID")):
        client.auto_role_cache[document.get("guildID")]["roles"] = {document.get("roleID"): document.get("delay")}
    else:
        client.auto_role_cache[document.get("guildID")] = {"roles": {document.get("roleID"): document.get("delay")}}
```

Hey, just wondering how if the `guildID` is in the dict, (meaning there are already roles in the dict) how I can add more roles into it, without deleting the old ones?
The code block above replaces the old data with the new data.

```
guildID {roles: {roleID1: delayHere, roleID2: delayHere}
```

Do you have to overwrite the entire dict every time you want to add new data? Or is there something similar to .append in a list?

Surely, I wouldn't have to get the old data, and then add it with the new data every time I want to add new things into the nested dict? That seems very inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can store multiple data, you may need to reconsider the structure based on which the data is stored. Currently, the `roles` field is just an object which which re-assigned replaces the old data. In order to get the expected behavior, i.e., storing multiple roles, you would have to store a **list of objects** instead.

So, effectively

```
{"roles": {...}}
```

is converted to something like:

```
{"roles": [{...}, {...}, ...]}
```

As you can see, now you can store multiple roles under the `roles` field. After you fix the structure of the document as specified, you may edit the code-block under if statement like so:

```
# Create a new role
new_role = {document.get("roleID"): document.get("delay")}

# Append the new role to the list
client.auto_role_cache[document.get("guildID")]["roles"].append(new_role)
```

**EDIT:** Based on the edits made to the question, you seem to have different *roleIDs*. In this case, you do not need to change the structure of the data. All you need to do is add a new field to the `roles` dictionary. You can use plain old indexing to get that working.

The edited code would be something like:

```
# Get the new role ID and delay
role_id = document.get("roleID")
delay = document.get("delay")

# Append the new role to the list
client.auto_role_cache[document.get("guildID")]["roles"][role_id] = delay
```

In the above code snippet, we are setting the `role_id` field to newly fetched `delay` value by using the `dictionary[key] = value` construct.

Comment: I have added edited answer which might help. Check it out :)

Comment: Thanks @Melvin . Sorry about my edit, after reading an answer I noticed I wasn't clear enough. Thank you very much for the answer :)

My output is now `{879917889040289792: {'roles': {882027759776432128: 1, 895398013378396161: 0}}}` which is exactly what was needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Keys for items in `dict` must be unique, so the example you give in the second block of code is impossible.

If you want to store multiple roles in `guildID[roles]`, make the value of that a list, which you can then append to or update as you wish.

A useful function here to ensure that you create the list if you don't have roles in a specific `dict` is `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> guildID = {}
>>> guildID
{}
>>> guildID.setdefault("roles", []).append("my_role")
>>> guildID.setdefault("roles", []).append("my_role2")
>>> guildID
{'roles': ['my_role', 'my_role2']}
>>>
```

---

EDIT: Based on the updates to the question, you might want instead:

```
>>> guildID = {}
>>> guildID.setdefault("roles", {})["my_role"] = 123
>>> guildID.setdefault("roles", {})["my_role2"] = 123
>>> guildID
{'roles': {'my_role': 123, 'my_role2': 123}}
```

This means you don't have to create a special case for the first role you add to also create `dict` `roles` in `guildID`.